# Run individual testng test and read testng.xml parameters using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I have parametrized testng tests and I would like to execute them (for debugging purposes) individually using IntelliJ "Run/Debug Test" feature.

When I do that, I have a different execution context because IntelliJ itself creates a new `testng.xml` file at `"user\.IdeaIC14\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml"` with no parameters info.

My code is:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setUpTestSuite(ITestContext context) throws Exception {

   Map<String, String> suiteParams = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getParameters();

   url = suiteParams.get("URL");
   login = suiteParams.get("login");
   pass = suiteParams.get("pass");  
}
```

When running test individually from IntelliJ `suiteParams` is empty.

Does anybody know any way to execute test or classes from IntelliJ and "link" them to original `testng.xml` file?

Comment: *testng tests* is it what you need?

Comment: @nikpon sorry, I dont get your question... I added some code to show my problem